# Exponential marks in Racket Numbers

Tags: racket

This is a question about Numbers in Racket.

---

According to [Reading Numbers](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-number%29) section in the Racket documentation, a number can be optionally suffixed by an *exp-mark* followed by an exact integer.

*exp-mark*s can be `s` | `l` | `d` | `e` | `f`

The documentation says:

> An *exponent-mark* in an inexact number serves both to specify an exponent and to specify a numerical precision. If single-flonums are supported and the `read-single-flonum` parameter is set to `#t`, the marks `f` and `s` specify single-flonums.

However there is no mention of what *exactly* the letters `s`, `l`, `d`, `e` and `f` specify.

```
1.2e2  ; 1.2*(10^2) = 120.0
1.2e-2 ; 1.2*(10^-2) = 0.012


1.2f2  ; 1.2*(10^2) = 120.0
1.2f-2 ; 1.2*(10^-2) = 0.012


1.2s2  ; 1.2*(10^2) = 120.0
1.2s-2 ; 1.2*(10^-2) = 0.012

1.2d2  ; 1.2*(10^2) = 120.0
1.2d-2 ; 1.2*(10^-2) = 0.012


1.2l2  ; 1.2*(10^2) = 120.0
1.2l-2 ; 1.2*(10^-2) = 0.012
```

It is apparent (from math) what `e` does, but does anyone know how the other are different (even though they produce the same result)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of these are inherited from Scheme. See https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r5rs-html/r5rs_8.html:

> The letters `s`, `f`, `d`, and `l` specify the use of short, single, double, and long precision, respectively. (When fewer than four internal inexact representations exist, the four size specifications are mapped onto those available. For example, an implementation with two internal representations may map short and single together and long and double together.) In addition, the exponent marker `e` specifies the default precision for the implementation.

Also note that in hex number, you can't use `d`, `e`, and `f` as an exponent marker, since they correspond to 13, 14, and 15 respectively.

```
> 1d1
10.0
> #x1d1 ; 16^2 + 13*16 + 1
465
> #x1s1 ; 1 * 16^1
16.0
```

Comment: Thank you, the [Syntax of numerical constants](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r5rs-html/r5rs_8.html#SEC54) sub-heading explains it. Also, yes, correct, I didn't consider that case for Hex representations.